# Advanced Custom Fields: fields all appear twice + field values won’t save

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a number of custom fields, I can't save the value of any of them. Also the whole series of custom fields shows up twice in my post.

Using ACF 5.8.3 and add-on Repeater Field 2.1.0, not using Gutemberg

Comment: Check by disabling templates and plugins, what conflicts with ACF

Comment: We need more information here. there is not enough to go on, how have you configured your fields, have you added any overrides to functions.php? show some code, or any explanation you can, disable all other plugins to make sure there is no conflicts

Comment: They show up twice in the admin or the frontend? Do you have fields that have the same id? Your question doesn't provide enough info.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Exporting fields as JSON, deleting all fields then importing the JSON did the trick, meaning I could save values again.

Not sure what happened.

Answer (score 2):

By using both of those plugins on a fresh Wordpress install, I can't repeat the problem you're having.

Try disabling your plugins, see if it works then and if that works, then re-enable all your plugins one-by-one to see what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I discovered the duplicate fields problem was due to a bad Wordpress database import (long story) resulting in duplicate fields in the wp_postmeta table. When I created a new page, the ACF fields worked normally. However with cloned pages, the duplicate fields problem persisted. Using a test page, I manually deleted the duplicate fields directly from the database table, and that solved the problem. However I still had 800+ pages to fix. I found a plugin called WP Sweep that did the trick. I backed up the database and then ran the "Duplicated Post Meta" cleanup sweep, and boom...problem solved!